# For loop producing of an output similar to finding corresponding parts of a similar triangle

Tags: for-loop, increment, dev-c++

pls help me. im trying to make a program in dev c++ that would accept a value of hypotenuse, longer leg, shorter leg and multiply it with the increment. kinda like a program that finds the corresponding parts of a triangle similar to the first triangle.

```
example (output)

enter hypotenuse:
enter longer leg:
enter shorter leg:
enter limitation:
example input(hypotenuse 5, longer leg 4, shorter leg 3, limitation 4)
```

the output i need to be shown is:

```
hypotenuse 5 10 15 20
longer leg 4 8 12 16
shorter leg 3 6 9 12
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to generate right angled triangles. From the result(output) that you have presented in the question the next triangle can generated by multiplying each sides with an integer value(k = 1,2,3,4,5,...). You can find more information [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Pythag/pythag.html). [This](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-75-lengths-of-wire-right-angle-triangle/) may also help.
**One probable solution can be:**

```
void display(const char* str, int value, int times)
{
  std::cout<<str;
  for(int i = 1; i<=times; i++)
  std::cout<<value*(i+1)<<'\t';
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
   int hyp,longLen,shortLen;
   int num;
   //I assume the input is a right angled triangle.
   cout<<"Enter hypotenuse: ";
   cin>>hyp;
   cout<<"Enter longer length: ";
   cin>>longLen;
   cout<<"Enter shorter length: ";
   cin>>shortLen;
   cout<<"Number of triangles to be displayed: ";
   cin>>num;
   display("Hypotenuse",hyp,num);
   display("Longer len",longLen,num);
   display("Shorter len",shortLen,num);
   return 0;
 }
```

Hope this helps. Enjoy!